# Remove leading and trailing newline characters from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have an `NSString` which consists of the text a user has entered into a `UITextView`. As a result, the string may have leading and trailing newline characters, along with newline characters within the string (if they hit the Return key to type on a new line). I would like to remove any newline characters from the beginning and end of the string, leaving any within the string intact.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

This trims also whitespace.
If you want to keep whitespace, just use the `newlineCharacterSet` instead.

Edited, as per @ghettopia correct suggestion about using the newlineCharacterSet instead of creating. Custom one.

Comment: Instead of creating a custom character set with only the newline character, how about the NSCharacterSet `newlineCharacterSet`?